# To apply digital signature on pdf using applets

Tags: applet, itext, digital-signature, bouncycastle

Im trying to implement digital signature on pdf using java applets. I have passed the required jars to the applet

```
<applet 
    width="1300"
    height="900"
    code="HelloWorld.class"
    archive="bcpkix-jdk15on-1.47.jar,bcprov-ext-jdk15on-1.47.jar,itextpdf-5.3.5.jar"> 
</applet>
```

but failed to run on browser even though it works on applet viewer. When I add these jars in the /jre/lib/ext folder then it runs on the browser as well.

I can't place the jars on the specified folder as the applet runs on client's browser and wont be a good solution to place the jars on the pc of every client.

Comment: Browsers more and more phase out support for applets.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot just add security providers without permission. You need to sign your code and have the user accept the applet to make changes to do that.

Comment: And I agree with mkl, this solution is starting to get old.